# Bringing river bed to the same height as surrounding ground in QGIS

Tags: qgis, hydrology, rivers, smoothing, stream

I have a DEM containing the current flow networks in an area. I also have a shapefile showing the same flow network. I would like to derive a new river network to see how water would flow if the current flow network wasn't there.

To do that, I need to "lift" the bed of the flow network, or "smooth" it to the same height as the surrounding ground.

Is there an easy way to do this? An option is to manually alter the height values for the data points, but that is a tedious and time-consuming task...

Comment: Do you have the river as a polygon layer?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your DEM? I imagine the rivers are cut into the smoother aspects of the DEM?

Comment: Create a new raster layer from your DEM, set the values where the river is to no data, then fill no data, drape your river network on the output